# Using a database in html without a server

Tags: html, database

I have a question regarding the client-side possibilities of a html webpage. I am currently working on my masters-thesis in aerospace engineering and plan to develop a design-catalog for inspiration. I chose html for this purpose, because I have a basic understanding, want to learn more and love the possibility of changing the style (e.g. width, height, padding, …) of all elements with a single command.

Unfortunately, there is no way of installing a local server or any other kind of software on the university computers. Besides, there is no way I get my colleagues (supervisor, Professor) to run additional software just to look at my catalog. Publishing the webpage on the intranet or internet is totally out of the question. The only possibility I have is using a browser (Firefox) and an Editor.

I thought about two different approaches:

1. Consider having a (Windows) folder containing images. Is it in any way possible to load all images of this specific folder into a webpage without using a server-side or installing any kind of software?
2. This would be even better: Is it in any way possible to make a website load data from a database into its own html code? I would like to be able to load only specific elements, e.g. all Designs with 2 Degrees of Freedom, or only load all images.
   Any kind of database! I don't care if it is mySQL, MariaDB, Excel or even a CSV file or something completely different.

Security of the code is not an issue. The data is sensitive, but I have full control over the database and code. It is a no point planned to publish the webpage or host it somewhere.

I would appreciate any kind of comment whether this is in any way possible, or whether I definitely need a server (e.g. xampp) to realize my approaches. If there is no possibility I would need to implement every image by hand or scratch the idea of the design catalogue.

Thank you in advance!

Best regards, REn0

Comment: Hmm, Firebase (Google's online database service) is free might work as a data store but I'm not sure if it's possible to secure it properly - i.e. make it so you have to log into Firebase when opening your app in the browser. *If* off-premise data storage is an option, of course. If it's not, there's local data storage options but they don't persist beyond the one browser that you're using.

Comment: Using Firebase with auth seems to be possible: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19293733/can-i-integrate-with-firebase-in-a-secure-way-without-having-user-authentication but reading your question a second time it may not be an option

Comment: For local databases in the browser, there's a lot out there, Google `browser local data storage`. Interesting discussion e.g. here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16815942/how-to-make-a-local-offline-database

Comment: thank you for your input! An online database is not possible for me. I looked also at the browser local data storage. This seems to be perfect, but is it true that I can only store about 5MB with this function? My catalog has about 20MB, tendency rising. This seems high for a webpage, but hosted locally on the harddisc there is really no problem. I found a work-around, but it is not perfect! Giving every image a number as name, I can use a for-loop:

Comment: <div id="EM"></div>

<script>
var text = "";
var i;
for (i = 1; i < 56; i++) {
    text += "<img src='EM-"+i+".PNG' style='width: 510px; float:left; padding-bottom:10px;'>";
}
document.getElementById("EM").innerHTML = text;
</script>

Comment: That sounds like a reasonable workaround, yeah. I can't think of any other option!